# Disable device authorization grant related endpoints

Tags: spring-authorization-server

Is there an easy way to disable the device authorization grant-related endpoints and removing `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code` from the `grant_types_supported` section in the `.well-known/openid-configuration` document?

I've both read through the documentation and the relevant source code, but I can't see any easy way to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I've read this github [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/616) about the authorization server, and to me it seems that is only possible to add some other specification to your openid-configuration json (you have to define a provider configuration Customizer,  [see here how](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/commit/0994a1e1e14263d106373e3397f8c5c44f9a7708#diff-ca4b9c945a7879f3295084d0dc482d46f195021de6f1c120e3bb6491cc25f387R513)), but it's not possible to delete them, unless you disabled the logic (in this case, the device flow authentication) in your application code.

I say this as I worked on a spring project where I had to remove the classes responsible for managing the device authentication flow, and, after that, neither the endpoints nor the consents were available in the opeind-configuration json.

I hope this can help you, please feel free to add more details if I didn't answer you properly.